# Internet Recovery instead of Hardware Diagnostics?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, apple-hardware-test, apple-diagnostics

I'm trying to run hardware diagnostics on my mid-2012 MacBook Pro. Whenever I restart when holding `D` it restarts into Internet Recovery mode instead of Hardware Diagnostics mode. Is there any way to reboot into Diagnostics mode (maybe via terminal?). My firmware password is off, and SIP is disabled.

Comment: those values are saved in NVRAM, so reset it